# how to transfer file from server to client via json

Tags: javascript, json, django, client-server

I am trying to transfer the processed pdf file on the server to the client side so that the user can download it.
Here is my code on the server -

```
@app.task
def pdf_protect(file_path, file_id, password):
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as file:
        reader = PdfReader(BytesIO(file.read()))

    writer = PdfWriter()
    writer.append_pages_from_reader(reader)
    writer.encrypt(password)

    output = io.BytesIO()
    writer.write(output)
    output.seek(0)

    send_notification.delay({'filename': 'result.pdf', 'content': base64.b64encode(output.read()).decode('utf-8')}, file_id)
```

In this code I use the [pypdf](https://pypi.org/project/pypdf/) library and encrypt the pdf with the given password.
After that, I try to convert the processed pdf file into bytes and pack it into json in order to send it to the client side via a websocket connection.

On the client side I have the following code -

```
chatSocket.onmessage = function (e) {
    const data = JSON.parse(e.data);
    var blob = new Blob([data.message.content], {type: "application/pdf"});
    console.log(data.message.content)
    downloadLink.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    downloadLink.download = data.message.filename;
    chatSocket.close();
};
```

In this code I get the data from the json and make a link to download the file.

But after downloading and opening the pdf file, the error "Failed to load the PDF document." or just a blank page.

**But** what happens when I send a response to the client via FileResponse and then use the same method to make a link to download the file and download it, then everything works fine.

This is what this code looks like −

```
protected_pdf_file = services.pdf_protect(form.cleaned_data['file'], form.cleaned_data['password'])
return FileResponse(
    protected_pdf_file,
    as_attachment=True,
    filename='protected_pdf.pdf',
)
```

And here is the code services.protect_pdf() -

```
def pdf_protect(pdf_file, password):
    reader = PdfReader(pdf_file)

    writer = PdfWriter()
    writer.append_pages_from_reader(reader)
    writer.encrypt(password)

    output = io.BytesIO()
    writer.write(output)
    output.seek(0)

    return output
```

Please tell me what the problem is and how to transfer files from the client to the server via json.
Thank you!

Comment: @K J, Thank you! I have already come up with the following solution - to store the file in storage (aws s3) and send a link to download the file via json.